# file="Personal.config" doesn't work in .net

Tags: c#, .net

After reading this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8818/Using-the-File-attribute-of-the-appSettings-elemen I tried adding a Personal.config file using attribute file on appSettings:

```
    <appSettings file="Personal.config">
        <add key="DatabaseServer" value="localhost" />
        <add key="DatabaseName" value="Test" />
...
    </appSettings>
```

My Personal.config:

```
<appSettings>   
    <add key="DatabaseServer" value="ALEXANDRA-PC" />
    <add key="DatabaseName" value="MyDatabase" />
...
</appSettings>
```

but it is still referencing the localhost server. Any ideas why it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: You need to set the connection string to the server.  What type of database are you using.  The connection string probably need some changes.

Comment: @jdweng I'm using MSSQL

Comment: You need a connection string.  The values in the config file are just the parameters into the connection string.  You need to find the connection string which is used to select the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked article contains this

> The path specified is relative to the main configuration file. For a
> Windows Forms application, this would be the binary folder (such as
> /bin/debug), not the location of the application configuration file.
> For Web Forms applications, the path is relative to the application
> root, where the web.config file is located

If the file cannot be located, `AppSettings["DatabaseServer"]`  will default to the values declared in the executable's config file, and if none are there it will return null. Check that your file is in the correct location, that it is named exactly the same as it is in the `File` attribute, and that you haven't made any mistakes with the file extension (i.e accidentally saving it as Personal.config.txt rather than Personal.config)

Comment: The naming and location are correct. Both config files are in the same directories and the name of the file I copy-pasted from renaming mode. It's still not loaded

Comment: Your custom config file needs to be in the bin/whatever folder along with the appName.exe.config, not with the app.config file in the project folder, is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I've solved the problem. It wasn't included in the csproj file. Thank you